# Samba 3.6.9 on CentOS 6.5 existing user unable to connect to new share

Tags: samba, centos-6

I've got a question about samba connectivity.  I installed a minimal installation of CentOS 6.5 and have it as a member server of AD, as per this guide: http://phreek.org/guides/centos-6-samba-ad-member-server

When I get info about a user with the wbinfo command, and use the --user-groups command, it returns the groups that user is a member of.

Now say I make a new group in AD and add this existing user to it.  Let's say I also add a user who has never connected or authenticated to the CentOS member server to this new group.

Using the wbinfo command, with --group-users, will list all users in the group as it should.  But, the existing user is unable to connect and wbinfo using --user-groups for that particular user does not show membership in the new group.

It's as if all users who have previously authenticated to the member server are frozen in their group memberships, regardless of what AD says; however users who have not authenticated to the member server before are able to connect to new shares fine.

What can I do to ensure samba updates individual users' group membership appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the blog guide you refer to and the reason is that group memberships are only updated upon re-authentication. It's the same when you add a user to a group through ADUC on a Windows DC. They need to logoff/logon or reboot their PC to have their group membership updated.

Comment: Thanks!  That's a duh moment for me - I should have remembered that!  Anyway, great guide and I've got that server working like a champ now.  Thanks again.